# get put and state in MonadState

Tags: haskell

I looked at the MonadState [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.3.1/docs/src/Control-Monad-State-Class.html#MonadState), I don't understand why these 3 functions won't get into dead loop? How does this get evaluated?

```
class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s where
    -- | Return the state from the internals of the monad.
    get :: m s
    get = state (\s -> (s, s))

    -- | Replace the state inside the monad.
    put :: s -> m ()
    put s = state (\_ -> ((), s))

    -- | Embed a simple state action into the monad.
    state :: (s -> (a, s)) -> m a
    state f = do
      s <- get
      let ~(a, s') = f s
      put s'
      return a
```

Comment: Out of interest, what does the '~' in the `let` statement do?

Comment: @radicality It makes the pattern "irrefutable". But it doesn't actually do anything in that case, since patterns in a let binding are irrefutable anyway. An irrefutable pattern match tells the compiler that you're correct about the constructor being matched, so it can delay destructuring it until the value of one of its arguments is actually forced. If you were wrong about the constructor being used, an exception will be raised at that time, but not earlier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definitions of `get,put,state` in the **class** declaration are the default implementations, which are meant to be overridden in actual instances of the class. In this way, the dead loop is broken: if an instance defines only `state`, then `get` and `put` are defined in terms of it using the default implementation in the class. Similarly, if an instance defines `get` and `put`, then `state` is defaulted.

For instance, the `Eq` type class might have been defined as follows:

```
class Eq a where
    (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
    x == y = not (x /= y)
    (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
    x /= y = not (x == y)

instance Eq Bool where
    True  == True  = True
    False == False = True
    _     == _     = False
    -- the (/=) operator is automatically derived
instance Eq () where
    () /= () = False
    -- the (==) operator is automatically derived
```

It is indeed common to have default self-referring implementations which evaluate to bottom unless something is redefined in the instances.